# NopCommerce google bot crawl redirected through login page

Tags: nopcommerce

I have a nopCommerce website, and bots cannot crawl my website. Google Search Console says that my sitemap is not valid XML but an HTML page - I think google bots are also redirected to the login page.

My ACL Public Store rules are all set to enabled for customers, and as you can see, you can visit all the pages without logging in. Why is Google's bot redirected through the login page? How can I fix this?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, there was an extra logging for that email, and that extra logging did not have the guest role assigned. I very, very much appreciate your help.